# Record match point saved in volleyball with rally point system?

Tags: trivia, records, volleyball

What is the record of saved match points in a volleyball match now that the rule is the rally poin system?

I mean that the team who saved match points finally wins the match

Answer (score 3):

The record for single set (when set goes to 25) seems this one:

```
54-52 13 gen 2002, Bre Banca Cuneo - Sisley Treviso
```

([Italian A1 stats](http://www.legavolley.it/Pillole.asp?Sezione=Gare&Tipo=TOPSCORE_MATCH&Anno=-1))

[This](http://www.volleykieldrecht.be/nl/news/was-het-gisteren-nu-de-langste-set-ooit) and also [this](http://www.volleyball-movies.net/fanclubs/discussion/the-longest-set-in-the-history-of-volleyball-329) source confirm this record, but I am not sure on the current validity.

Answer (score 2):

The record in the Dutch competition is:
[57-55](https://www.facebook.com/volleybalnl/photos/a.126387217439024.29600.123272957750450/921607021250369/?type=3)

This was an amateur-level match, three years after introduction of rally point (must be around 2003)